# Magento - Add product programmatically to cart through observer

Tags: magento, events, observers

Here is my questions: What is the right event to hook in for adding a product to quote programmatically (entry sales_flat_quote_item table). Also i have to catch the items/products added to cart from an user/customer, because their data informations will determine the product which will be added programmatically. So the scenario would be:

1. user/customer adds a product to cart
2. find the right event for hook in
3. fetch informations about the products added to cart
4. add additional product to cart based on a product id and modified its data

In my opinion its better to work with the quote, before the products are written to the database.

I figure out how to add it through **Mage_Sales_Model_Quote::_addCatalogProduct()**. But i would like to do it through an event observer instead of overwriting core classes.

**EDIT**

After more research and suggestions here in the post, i was able to get it working. The key thing for me was the understanding of the objects in the observer, their classes and class methods with

```
var_dump(get_class($quote)); // $item // $product
var_dump(get_class_methods($quote)); // $item // $product
```

Now knowing the methods are available its easier to figure it out:

Event:

```
        <events>
        <checkout_cart_product_add_after>
            <observers>
                <unifiedarts_configurablebundleset>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>Namespace_ConfigurableBundleSet_Model_Observer</class>
                    <method>salesQuoteEditItems</method>
                </unifiedarts_configurablebundleset>
            </observers>
        </checkout_cart_product_add_after>
    </events>
```

And observer data:

```
public function salesQuoteEditItems($observer)
{
    $event = $observer->getEvent();
    $item = $event->getQuoteItem();
    $product = $item->getProduct();
    $quote = $item->getQuote();

    $parent = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product->getParentProductId());

    if($parent->getTypeId() == 'bundle')
    {

        if($product->getTypeId() == 'configurable')
        {

            if ($simpleItem = $item->getOptionByCode('simple_product'))
            {
                // check if the simple product is in the table
                if(!$quote->hasProductId($simpleItem->getProduct()->getId()))
                {
                    echo '<br /><br /> no simple, add it';
                    echo ' simple id '.$simpleItem->getProduct()->getId();

                    $simple = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($simpleItem->getProduct()->getId());
                    $quoteItem = Mage::getModel('sales/quote_item')->setProduct($simple);
                    $parentItem = ( $item->getParentItem() ? $item->getParentItem() : $item );

                    echo 'simple id '.$simpleItem->getProduct()->getId();

                    $item->setRowWeight($product->getWeight());

                    $quoteItem->setQuote($quote);
                    $quoteItem->setQty('1');
                    $quoteItem->setParentItem($parentItem);
                    $quoteItem->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId());
                    $quoteItem->setOriginalCustomPrice(0);

                    $quote->addItem($quoteItem);
                    $quote->save();

                }
                else
                {
                    echo 'simple found change someting'; die;
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

The hole thing is that my extension has to add an configured Item with the bundle. The product view is working. The hard task is to get it in the cart. Now, everything is working fine till going back and add the product again with different (configured) options.

You see above i try to check for the simple product (which i add manually). The code generates two new rows in the **sales_flat_quote_item** table.

How can i delete the old two entries, or is there a different better approach to set the new data? thanks :)

[image]

Comment: in which stage do you want to add product in cart?

Comment: thats the point, i don't know whats the best time to add it. i guess together with the other products added to cart, inserting it to the quote object after i run the check on the quote items

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Declare event observers in config.xml

```
<events>
            <checkout_cart_product_add_after>
                <observers>
                    <custommodule>
                        <class>custommodule/observer</class>
                        <method>cartProductAddAfter</method>
                    </custommodule>
                </observers>
            </checkout_cart_product_add_after>
            <checkout_cart_product_update_after>
                <observers>
                    <custommodule>
                        <class>custommodule/observer</class>
                        <method>cartProductUpdateAfter</method>
                    </custommodule>
                </observers>
            </checkout_cart_product_update_after>
</events>
```

Develop the Observers handlers

```
class Vendor_Custommodule_Model_Observer 
{
    /* If you'd like to do the same while updating the shopping cart*/
    public function cartProductUpdateAfter($observer)
    {
        $this->cartProductAddAfter($observer);
    }

    public function cartProductAddAfter($observer)
    {
        $product = $observer->getEvent()->getProduct();
        $currentItem = $observer->getEvent()->getQuoteItem();
        $quote = $currentItem->getQuote();
        $quoteItems = $quote->getItems();

        /* Detect Product ID and Qty programmatically */
        $idToAdd = "ANY PRODUCT ID";
        $qty = 1;

        $productToAdd = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
        /* @var $productToAdd Mage_Catalog_Model_Product */
        $productToAdd->load($idToAdd);

        $this->_addProductToCart($productToAdd, $qty);
    }

    protected function _addProductToCart($product, $qty)
    {
        $cart = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart');
        /* @var $cart Mage_Checkout_Model_Cart */
        if ($product->getId()) {
            $cart->addProduct($product, $qty);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: your suggestion helpt me out. check my edit with the new info provided

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
<events>
    <checkout_cart_product_add_after>
        <observers>
            <additionalproduct>
                <type>singleton</type>
                <class>YourPackage_YourModule_Model_Observer</class>
                <method>additionalProduct</method>
            </additionalproduct>
        </observers>
    </checkout_cart_product_add_after>
</events>
```

Code for Observer class:

```
class YourPackage_YourModule_Model_Observer 
{

    public function additionalProduct(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
        $item = $observer->getQuoteItem(); // current Quote object
        $product = $observer->getProduct(); // current Product object

        // apply your logice here 
        // for example 
        $id = '100'; // Replace id with your product id
        $qty = '2'; // Replace qty with your qty
        $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($id);
        $cart = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart');
        $cart->init();
        $cart->addProduct($_product, array('qty' => $qty));
        $cart->save();
        Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->setCartWasUpdated(true);


    }
}
```

Hope this help!

Comment: why do you use the cart object instead of quote object? i assume that in your code the products are allready in the cart. There are some things missing like the quote id. I need it to add the product to same quote

Comment: Please elaborate your requirement bit more so that I can let you know right event where you can proceed. thanks

Comment: I edited my post with more information and the current progress, take a look